# Si Captcha Version 2.7.7.1 - Wordpress - Unreadable CAPTCHA token file error

Tags: php, wordpress

The new version of Si Captcha (2.7.7.1) gives the error `Unreadable CAPTCHA token file error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking online, everywhere says to add a temp folder at `/wp-content/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/captcha` folder path and give it permissions `777`.  This seems to no longer be the case.  It seems that you must now change the `cache` folder's permissions to `777` within this same folder path for the latest version.  Just putting this here so others know.

Comment: But perhaps avoid `777`, right? The directory just needs to be writable by the web server. You can either run the web server as a user that can read your permissions, or update the permissions to provide for the user/group under which the server runs.

Answer (score -2):

Giving Permission in /wp-content/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/captcha doesn't work anymore. May be it was working in the previous versions. 
I have solved it by going in the below path and deleting some of the files manually. It worked for me!

wp-content/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/captcha/cache

Comment: It would help improve the answer if you can add 1. what kind of permissions giving doesn't work anymore 2. Which files (extensions/names) to be deleted or you deleted which worked for you. 3. In general, be a little descriptive about your answer.